# Is there any International standard for representing phonemes?

Tags: ipa, transcription

While for phones we use IPA but it seems that there is no equivalent for phonemes

Comment: Since every phonemic system is particular to one language or dialect, and therefore has its own unique structure, there can be no international standard.

Comment: Incidentally, [APA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americanist_phonetic_notation), a strange variation in my view, is still in use internationally. Does not contribute much to your hope for a standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IPA is neutral as to analysis: it is used to represent sound at any level, including underlying, intermediate form, phonemic transcription and surface realization.

Comment: There is no standard way to use IPA as a phonemic system for a given language in general, but there is also no good reason for there to be one, since a single language often has multiple possible analyses which are not just "different conventions" but represent different underlying assumptions about the language. For this reason, I think a standard would be actually detrimental.

Comment: Once you decide what the constituents of a phoneme are, you can represent them more or less unambiguously. But that decision is not the notation's to make.

Comment: There is: if a language has a high front round vowel as a phoneme, you use *y*. If it instead has a mid front round vowel as a phoneme, you use *ø*. All transcriptional decisions are *decisions*. IPA simply tells you what the conventional letters are. So *ʃ* is IPA, and *š* is not. IPA does not do the analysis for you.

Answer (score 3):

As @user6726 points out, IPA can be used for phonemes, and in fact is.

The IPA guidelines (at least the 1948 version) suggests that if you're using IPA for a broad transcription (and a phonemic analysis is broad), you should prefer the more familiar-looking, Roman glyph over the less familiar. So if you have a choice of <e> or <ɛ> for a phoneme, use <e>.